# Setting different thresholds dependent on what filename ends with in ImageJ macro

Tags: imagej, imagej-macro

I have a folder containing many images. These are grouped into sets of three images where one filename ends in `dsRed).tif`, another filename ends in `FITC).tif` and the other filename ends in `DAPI).tif`.

How can I tell ImageJ to do different stuff to each image dependent on which filename ending it has?

I have tried to set up macros to run different thresholds, e.g.:

```
//run("Brightness/Contrast...");
setMinAndMax(0, 20000);
close();
```

to the different filenames based on scripts found here:
http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/open-file-with-specific-partial-name-td5002910.html
and here:
http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/macros/Batch_RGB_Merge.txt but I am having trouble with formatting if else functions with my three filename endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the file names with subsequent [`if ... else`](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/macros.html#if) statements:

```bs
if (endsWith(filename,"dsRed).tif") {
    // do dsRed processing here
} else if (endsWith(filename,"FITC).tif") {
    // do FITC processing here
} else if (endsWith(filename,"DAPI).tif") {
    // do DAPI processing here
}
```

If you want to group files that contain the same base name, loop only over one of your channels (e.g. `dsRed`) and use [`replace`](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html#replace):

```bs
replace(filename, "dsRed).tif", "FITC).tif");
```

to process the respective other channel within each loop iteration.

Comment: Many thanks Jan.

The macro:

dir = getDirectory("image"); 
name=getTitle; 
if (endsWith(name,"dsRed).tif")) {
    //run dsRed stuff
run("Close");
} else if (endsWith(name,"FITC).tif")) {
    //run FITC stuff
run("Close");
} else if (endsWith(name,"DAPI).tif")) {
    //run DAPI stuff
run("Close");
}

worked nicely.